# BigCommerce Add Products To Cart API

Tags: api, addition, product, cart, bigcommerce

I'm just setting up my first BigCommerce store, and I'd like to know if I can use their API to add products to a shopper's cart and forward them to the checkout page programmatically?

The problem I'm trying to solve is creation of bundles of products in the store.  I need to have each product in a bundle show up as a separate line item and sku on the order, but BigCommerce does not natively support this.  The next best thing I can think of is to send the user to a specially crafted php page that will add the constituent parts to their cart, then forward them to the checkout page.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?  Is there a simple way to do this that I've missed?

Comment: You can create an order with an API and add products/variants to it. It will solve your problem. But, you cannot forward them to a checkout page. You will have to process that order manually in your admin panel.

Comment: I've done some hacking around with the form that adds a product to your cart on the product page, my hunch is that it'd be possible to add additional products as hidden fields and submit them all at once. I'll play with this later and respond if that's the case.

Comment: @RSG Hi Sir. I am currently working on to find out if it's possible to use the API just to add a custom product into the shopping cart then redirect the user to the checkout page and so far to no avail. Every question asked about this here was never answered. Would it be possible to use the API just to add a custom product to the shopping cart and after that, just let the default company code handle the rest of it like checking out and so? I'd really be grateful if you could point me to the right direction. Thank you very much Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cart api to
- Create cart
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/cart.html#post-carts

and use the created cart id to

- Generate cart URL 
  https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/cart.html#post-carts-cartid-redirect_urls

Then you can move the user to this url